# Logback-access 1.0.13: SMTPAppender shows PARSER_ERROR in subject

Tags: jetty, logback

The subject of my SMTPAppender in logback access always displays a
%PARSER_ERROR when I place a variable there (pattern).

For the subject line:

```xml
   <subject>TESTING: %logger{20} - %m</subject>
```

I'm getting this as subject:

```
TESTING: %PARSER_ERROR[logger] - %PARSER_ERROR[m]
```

I'm using the 1.0.13 version in Jetty and my logback-access.xml is as
follows:

```xml
<appender name="SMTP"
  class="ch.qos.logback.access.net.SMTPAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.access.PatternLayout">
      <encoder>
        <pattern>%fullRequest%n%n%fullResponse</pattern>
      </encoder>
    </layout>
    <Evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.access.net.URLEvaluator">
      <URL>index</URL>
    </Evaluator>
    <from>blahz@blah.com</from>
    <subject>TESTING: %logger{20} - %m</subject>
    <smtpHost>localhost</smtpHost>
    <to>zzz@blah.com</to>
</appender>

<appender-ref ref="SMTP" />
```

When I omit the *subject* tag at all, I get the following message:

```
09:57:01,618 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.access.net.SMTPAppender[SMTP] - About to send out SMTP message "%PARSER_ERROR[m]
" to [zzz@blah.com]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
     `<encoder>
        <pattern>%fullRequest%n{}%n{}%fullResponse</pattern>
      </encoder>`

Referenced in Logback documentation: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#restrictionsOnLiterals

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the issue. I have tried with a single variable, for example %fullRequest